# Node cluster with socket.io

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have cluster setup via elastic beanstalk and that works well. However, when I try to implement socket.io the web sockets fail for being unable to communicate across servers. So, I switched to `socket.io-redis` and this is the code that I've used but it keeps giving me `Cannot /Get` in the browser when I go to `localhost:3000`

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var os = require('os');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // we create a HTTP server, but we do not use listen
  // that way, we have a socket.io server that doesn't accept connections
  var server = require('http').createServer();
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

  io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

  setInterval(function() {
    // all workers will receive this in Redis, and emit
    io.emit('data', 'payload');
  }, 1000);

  for (var i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  }); 
}else{
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  var http = require('http');
  var server = http.createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

  io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('data', 'connected to worker: ' + cluster.worker.id);
  });

  app.listen(3000);
}
```

Mind you, I have run `redis-server` in the terminal and I've downloaded the modules.

Comment: Have you realized you didn't define a route for ``"/"``?

Comment: Thank you! solve with this`app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});`